# Block two pipeline groups to run simultaneous

Tags: go-cd

I have 2 pipeline groups which run on same machine. Both have one pipeline which starts the rest of group. This pipeline contains the logic to start a service inside a container with a specific configuration and i want to wait all the group finish the work, before the second group can start and destroy the container and create another. I don't want to make a loop, to run automatically one after the other finishes. I want just to block possibility to start a group while the other group runs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is undue coupling between your pipelines, and the best approach would be to reduce the coupling, for example by each pipeline spinning up their own container.

If that is not an option, you could try to build a pipeline graph like this:

```
Group1-A  \         / Group2-A
Group1-B  -- dummy -- Group2-B
Group1-C  /         \ Group2-C
```

though I'm not sure that actually solves your problem.